# Passing C# Web service Parameters to PHP Application

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to passing C# Web service Parameters to PHP Application but not getting below is my code. Actually I am passing username and password xml format because no buddy should not see that credential while passing.

Below is my C# Web service using asp.net web form button click to redirect PHP application.

```
  [WebMethod]
public string POSTXml(string username, string password)
{
    WebRequest req = null;
    WebResponse rsp = null;
    try
    {
        StringBuilder strRequest = new StringBuilder();

        string url = "http://xyz.in/getuser.php/";

        req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        writer.WriteLine(username,password);
        writer.Close();

        rsp = req.GetResponse();

        var sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();

        return responseText;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("There was a problem sending the message");
    }
}
```

Below is my button click code.

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    localhost.WebService objserv1 = new localhost.WebService();
    Label.Text = objserv1.POSTXml("nagapavani", "tech@1234");


}
```

Actually when user will button click passing some values to web service and through web service want to pass that value to php application. Is there Other way to achieve that requirement. When I am going to button click not going to redirect and taken this code from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the data as following. Convert it to a byte array and write it to the request stream:

```
[WebMethod]
public string POSTXml(string username, string password)
{
    WebRequest req = null;
    WebResponse rsp = null;
    try
    {
        string data = "user=" + username + "&password=" + password;
        string url = "http://xyz.in/getuser.php/";

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


        WebReq.Method = "POST";
        WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        using (Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

            using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    return strReader.ReadToEnd();                            
                }                        
            }
            WebResp.Close();
       }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("There was a problem sending the message");
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: U did not added return, please check, 'WebService.POSTXml(string, string)': not all code paths return a value. @Johan

Comment: It was meant as an example, which you can implement in your own code. Not just copy/paste. But returning variable 'result' won't be a problem I guess? :) (example code is edited)

Comment: when I will execute web service your web service and inserted two values and redirecting to <string xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xsi:nil="true"/> .@Johan

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: when I button click getting error: An exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll but was not handled in user code. @Johan

Comment: Please check my button click code what I am passing there. @Johan

Comment: Please I am not redirecting to that php application check once your code. @Johan

Comment: I added your edited code also getting error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. @Johan

Comment: check https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/915599/you-receive-one-or-more-error-messages-when-you-try-to-make-an-http-request-in-an-application-that-is-built-on-the-.net-framework-1.1-service-pack-1

Comment: Please tell what is error I check and getting confused, i am using visual studio 2013 and did you try this code in your system. @johan

Comment: Yep. Its copy/pasted rom my own code and only tweaked a little

Comment: Then why it is not working, please check once again, its very urgent. @Johan